# Custom Server action to send trigger message

Tags: action, odoo

I am trying to understand Server Action in which when a state is changed from `draft` to `confirm`, a message is sent to the email provided.

There is no error as such in program, but the mail is not sent to custom email.

The codes are as follows:

**notebook_server_action.xml**:

```
<!-- demo automated actions sending message after state transition -->
<record id="filter_draft_lead" model="ir.filters">
    <field name="name">Draft Leads notebook</field>
    <field name="model_id">notebook.server_action</field>
    <field name="domain">[('state','=','confirm')]</field>
    <field name="user_id" eval="False" />
</record>
<record id="action_email_reminder_lead" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Message @ confirm state</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_notebook_server_action" />
    <field name="condition">True</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="state">email</field>
    <field name="email">object.email</field>
    <field name="subject">Check 1 2 3</field>
    <field name="message">11111111111111</field>
</record>
<record id="rule_set_reminder_lead" model="base.action.rule">
    <field name="name">Send mail when status changed to confirm</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_notebook_server_action" />
    <field name="sequence">1</field>
    <field name="filter_id" ref="filter_draft_lead" />
    <field name="trg_date_id" ref="field_notebook_server_action_note_date" />
    <field name="trg_date_range">0</field>
    <field name="trg_date_range_type">minutes</field>
    <field name="server_action_ids" eval="[(6,0,[ref('action_email_reminder_lead')])]" />
</record>
```

**notebook.py**

```
class notebook(osv.osv):
    _name = "notebook.server_action"
    _description = "Simple Notebook"
    _columns = {
        'name' : fields.char('Title', size=30, required=True),
        'note' : fields.text('Note'),
            'email': fields.char('Email', size=120, required=True),
        'note_date' : fields.datetime('Date'),
        'state': fields.selection([('draft', 'Draft'), ('confirm', 'Confirmed')],
            'Status', required=True, readonly=True),
            }
    _defaults = {
        'state': 'draft',
        'note_date' : lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    }
    def button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'confirm'})
```

**notebook_view.xml**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="notebook_server_actiontree_view">
    <field name="name">notebook.server_action.tree</field>
    <field name="model">notebook.server_action</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Notebook">
            <field name="name" />
            <field name="note" />
            <field name="note_date" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="notebook_server_actionform_view">
    <field name="name">notebook.server_action.form</field>
    <field name="model">notebook.server_action</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Notebook" version="7.0">
            <header>
                <button name="button_confirm" states="draft" string="Confirm"
                    type="object" />
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar" />
            </header>
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="name" />
                    <field name="note" />
                    <field name="note_date" />
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_notebook_server_actionform">
    <field name="name">notebook.server_action</field>
    <field name="res_model">notebook.server_action</field>
</record>
<menuitem name="NotebookParent" icon="terp-project" id="NotebookParent_menu" />
<menuitem name="NotesChild" parent="NotebookParent_menu" id="NotesChild_menu" />
<menuitem name="Header" parent="NotesChild_menu" id="Header_menu_mainform"
    action="action_notebook_server_actionform" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to such triggers is not so much the `ir.actions.server` (Server Action) entry but the `base.action.rule` (Automated Action) that specifies a trigger on a specific model (here `notebook.server_action`) for any change on a record that matches the condition(s).

There are actually 2 kinds of Automated Actions, those based on pre/post-conditions, and those based on timing conditions.

1. Those that have no timing condition (`trg_date_id` field **not set**) are executed right after the corresponding creation or update event takes place, provided the pre/post-conditions are satisfied. Automated Actions with a pre-condition are not considered when a record is newly created, as there is no `"pre"` state to check.
2. Those based on a timing condition (`trg_date_id` field **is set**) are processed regularly by a background job, and must not have a pre-condition (`filter_pre_id`), because the `"pre"` state is not known at that time. They will be executed for each record that matches their post-condition (`filter_id`), provided that the specified delay has elapsed since the last execution of the Automated Action.

Now when an Automated Action is executed, the corresponding Server Actions are run, and in your case a new email should be sent immediately. This depends on the proper configuration of an Outgoing Mail Server in your database.
If the email cannot be sent (e.g. if malformed or with invalid addresses), the system will raise an error, but you may not see it as it will happen in the background when the scheduler processes timing-based Automated Actions.

Have you double-checked the email config (Settings/Email/Outgoing Mail Servers)?

Have you perhaps disabled the scheduled job for the Automated Actions, called *"Check Action Rules"*?

What does the OpenERP logs say? Any error appears?

**Update:** Watch out for tricky cases when "timing conditions" are coupled with pre-conditions: if the pre-condition is not met for a record R at time T when the scheduler runs, but the delay specified by the timing condition for R has passed, then R will not be checked when scheduler runs at T+1 because it will consider that is has already been executed last time (it keeps no state of past executions expect the last execution date)

In your example it seems you want to trigger the mail as soon as the note is confirmed and the note date is passed, but you will not get the desired effect if the scheduler has already executed after the date.

You might be able to trick the system to do what you want by moving the condition check into the server action, keeping only the timing condition in the Automated Actions, and having the server action move the "date" field of the record in the future if the condition is not met yet. This should make sure that the record is still considered next time the scheduler runs. However this is a bit convoluted and you might want to reconsider your use case to do something simpler.

Comment: `1.` All Ok outgoing mail configuration
`2.` Status in Enable @ Automated action
`3.` No error/ info @ traceback

Comment: by using `'note_date' : lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),`

I have given current time i.e. trigger date and when state is changed to `confirm`, the server action should occur. and there is no effect or action done at **`LOG FILE`**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think it might then be a tricky case of combining the timing condition with a pre-condition. I've updated the answer to explain what I mean.

Comment: so if I change the rule set as 0 mins to 5 mins will it work properly

Comment: so I have to use workflow to send my mail when the state transition is done

Comment: Yes using a workflow would seem like a more appropriate way to handle this use case. I tried to describe a workaround in my answer but it's complex and rather hacky, so a workflow is better if you don't mind adding one.

Answer (score 0):

For tests you can change field 'last_run' in table 'base_action_rule' to begin of current day or earlier
Then it will run fine.